# CImg saving images changes values?

Tags: c++, image, rgb, pixel, cimg

So I am using the CImg library to have some fun with images...
The issue is that when I open a file to change its RGB values and save, the modified image does not retain the changed values OR the original value.

```
CImg<unsigned char> image_out( img.c_str() );
image_out(0,0,0) = 253; //reset new rgb values
image_out(0,0,1) = 248;
image_out(0,0,2) = 251;
image_out.save( "out.jpeg" );
```

Then when I open the image again, I get this as the new RGB values...

```
R: 249  G: 249  B: 249
```

I don't really understand why the values aren't being saved to the ones I set...

edit:
Sorry also mentioning I KNOW the initial value of the pixel (respect to RGB) is 255, 255, 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use jpeg, this is a destructive image format that doesn't preserve the values, due to the Dct compression.
Use .png or. Bmp instead.